# Can't import numpy from pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, anaconda

I have Anaconda3. When I use its interpreter from Pycharm  or directly from the folder to import numpy I get the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>
     16 try:
---> 17     from . import multiarray
     18 except ImportError as exc:

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py in <module>
     13
---> 14 from . import overrides
     15 from . import _multiarray_umath

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py in <module>
      6
----> 7 from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
      8     add_docstring, implement_array_function, _get_implementing_args)

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d4cdadb62aa7> in <module>
----> 1 import numpy

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    140     from . import _distributor_init
    141
--> 142     from . import core
    143     from .core import *
    144     from . import compat

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>
     45 """ % (sys.version_info[0], sys.version_info[1], sys.executable,
     46         __version__, exc)
---> 47     raise ImportError(msg)
     48 finally:
     49     for envkey in env_added:

ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.7 from "C:\Users\noamw\Anaconda\python.exe",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.17.4" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.

Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

However, when I use it from ipython after activating my environment, using conda, it works just fine. It's really frustrating that I can't create a Pycharm project like this.
Would really appreciate any help
Thanks

Comment: i got simal issue

Answer (score 2):

Setting your environment as the interpreter for PyCharm should work. Got to `Preferences` --> `Project` --> `Project Interpreter`. In the drop down menu select your conda environment. Set it to something like: `~/Anaconda3/envs/myenvname/bin/python`

Comment: I have done that, unfortunately that did not solve the problem. It can run python, just not import numpy, or sqlite

Answer (score 2):

It is a bummer that Pycharm has not looked into this issue and has not come up with a solution for it.

Most solutions I found suggest removing numpy and reinstalling it using `pip install numpy`, which basically defeats the purpose of having a conda environment and getting its benefits like conda revisions; not to mention the bad practice of using both pip and conda in the same environment.

Until Pycharm gets to the bottom of this, you can get around this issue following this:

1. Activate your environment in command prompt.
2. Use `set` command to print all environment variables.
3. Copy the `PATH` environment variable.

[image]

4. Add it to the environment variables of your Run/Debug configurations.

[image]

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. Should be rated higher.